# Annihilator of tensor product when $R$ is domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain and $M$ and $N$ be two faithful $R$-modules. Is it true that $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M\otimes_R N)=0$?

Answer (score 5):

No. $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ are faithful $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, but $\ \mathbb{Q}\otimes _{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=0$. However this is true if $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated (no noetherian hypothesis needed), see e.g. Bourbaki *Commutative Algebra* II, §4, Proposition 18.